# Prove that the integral of a differential form on an open set is well defined.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms, riemann-integration

What to follow is a summary of part of the sixth chapter of the text *Analysis on Manifolds* by James Munkres.

> **Definition**
>
> Given $x\in\Bbb R^n$ we define a tangent vector to $\Bbb R^n$ at $x$ to be a pair $(x;\vec v)$ where $\vec v\in\Bbb R^n$. The set of tangent vector to $\Bbb R^n$ at $x$ forms a vector space if we define
> $$
> (x;\vec v)+(x;\vec w):=(x;\vec v+\vec w)\\
> c(x;v\vec):=(x;c\vec v)
> $$
> It is called the tangent space to $\Bbb R^n$ at $x$ and is denoted by the symbol $\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)$.
>
> **Definition**
>
> Let $A$ be open set in $\Bbb R^n$. A $k$-tensor field in $A$ is a function $\omega$ assigning to each $x\in A$ a $k$-tensor defined on the vector space $\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)$, that is
> $$
> \omega(x)\in\mathcal L^k\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)
> $$
> for each $x\in A$. In particular if it happens that $\omega(x)$ is an alternanting $k$-tensor for each $x\in A$ then $\omega$ is called a differential form of order $k$ on $A$.
>
> Now if the vectors $\vec v_1,...,\vec v_n$ form a basis of $\Bbb R^n$ then the vectors $(x;\vec v_1),...,(x;\vec v_n)$ form a bsis of $\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)$ and thus we define a $1$-form $dx^i$ on $\Bbb R^n$ by letting that
> $$
> [dx^i(x)](x;\vec v_j)=\delta^i_j
> $$
> for any $x\in\Bbb R^n$ and for any $j=1,...,n$. Well it is possible to prove that if $\omega$ is a $k$-form defined in any open set $A$ then
> $$
> \sum_{i_1<...<i_k}f_{i_1,..,i_k}dx^{i_1}\curlywedge...\curlywedge dx^{i_k}
> $$
> where $f_{i_1,...,i_k}$ is for any ascending $k$-tuple of indices $i_1,...,i_k$ is a scalar function defined on $A$.
>
> **Definition**
>
> Let $A$ be open in $\Bbb R^k$; let be $\alpha:A\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ be of class $C^\infty$; let be $B$ and open set of $\Bbb R^n$ containing $\alpha[A]$. We define a dual transformation of forms
> $$
> \alpha^*:\Omega^l(B)\rightarrow\Omega^l(A)
> $$
> as follows: given a $0$-form $f:B\rightarrow\Bbb R$ on $B$ we define a $0$-form $\alpha^* f$ on $A$ by setting $\alpha^* f:=f\circ\alpha$ and given an $l$-form on $B$ with $l>0$ we define an $l$-form $\alpha^*\omega$ on $A$ by the equation
> $$
> [\alpha^*\omega(x)]\big((x;v\vec v_1),...,(x;\vec v_l)\big):=[\omega(\alpha(x)]\big((\alpha(x);D\alpha(x)\cdot\vec v_1),...,(\alpha(x);D\alpha(x)\cdot\vec v_l)\big)
> $$
> for any $x\in A$ and for any $\vec v_1,...,\vec v_k\in\Bbb R^n$.
>
> **Definition**
>
> Let $A$ be an open set in $\Bbb R^k$ and let be $\eta$ a $k$-form defined in $A$ so that it can be written uniquely in the form
> $$
> \eta=fdx^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dx^k
> $$
> for any scalar function $f$ defined on $A$. So we define the integral of $\eta$ over $A$ by the equation
> $$
> \int_A\eta:=\int_A f
> $$
> provided the latter integral exists.
>
> This definition seems to be coordinate-dependent: indeed the function $f$ dependes to the choice of a basis in $\Bbb R^n$. One can, however, formulate the definition in a coordinate-free fashion: specifically if $\vec v_1,...,\vec v_k$ is **any** right-handed orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^k$ tehn it is an lemenetary exercise to show that
> $$
> \int_A\eta=\int_{x\in A}[\eta(x)]\big((x;\vec v_1),...,(x;\vec v_k)\big)
> $$
> Thus the integral of $\eta$ does not depend on the choice of any orthonormal basis in $\Bbb R^k$ although it does depend on the orientation of $\Bbb R^k$.
>
> **Definition**
>
> Let $A$ be open in $\Bbb R^k$; let $\alpha A\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ be a $k$-parametrized manifold. If $\omega$ is a $k$-form defined in an open set of $\Bbb R^n$ containing $Y_\alpha:=\alpha[A]$ then we define the integral of $\omega$ on $Y_\alpha$ by letting
> $$
> \int_{Y_\alpha}\omega:=\int_A\alpha^*\omega
> $$
> So now I would like to know if it is possible to define the integral of a differential form on an open set independently of any basis and not only for orthonormal bases.

So if $dx^{1}\curlywedge...\curlywedge dx^{k}$ and $dy^{1}\curlywedge...\curlywedge dy^k$ are the $k$-elementary form with respect two any different bases $\mathcal V:=\{\vec v_1,...,\vec v_k\}$ and $\mathcal W:=\{\vec w_1,...,\vec w_k\}$ then there exist two scalar functions $f$ and $g$ defined on $A$ such that
$$
f dx^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dx^k=\eta=g dy^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dy^k
$$
so that they are related by the equation
$$
g(x)=[\eta(x)]\big((x;\vec w_1),...,(x;\vec w_k)\big)=\\ [(f\cdot dx^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dx^k)(x)]\big((x;\vec w_1),...,(x;\vec w_k)\big)=...=f(x)[dx^1(x)\wedge...\wedge dx^k(x)]\big((x;\vec w_1),...,(x;\vec w_k)\big)=\\
f(x)\det\begin{pmatrix}[dx^1(x)](x;\vec w_1)&&\cdots&&[dx^1(x)](x;\vec w_k)\\
\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
[dx^k(x)](x;\vec w_1)&&\cdots&&[dx^k(x)](x;\vec w_k)\end{pmatrix}=f(x)\det\begin{pmatrix}w^1_1&&\cdots&&w^1_k\\
\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
w^k_1&&\cdots&&w^k_k\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $w^i_j$ are the components of the basis $\mathcal W$ with respect the basis $\mathcal V$. So by the previous equation clearly we conclude that generally if the two bases are not orthonormal then
$$
\int_A g=\det\begin{pmatrix}w^1_1&&\cdots&&w^1_k\\
\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
w^k_1&&\cdots&&w^k_k\end{pmatrix}\cdot\int_A f\neq\int _A f
$$
and thus the integral of $\eta$ it is not uniquely determined. Anyway I tried to expalin this using the following theorem

> **Theorem**
>
> Let $g:A\rightarrow B$ be a diffeomorphism of open sets in $\Bbb R^k$. Assume $\det Dg$ does not change sign on $A$. Let $\beta: B\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ be a map of class $C^\infty$; let $Y_\beta:=\beta[B]$. Let $\alpha:=\beta\circ g$ and thus $Y_\alpha:=\alpha[A]$. If $\omega$ is a $k$-form defined in an open set of $\Bbb R^n$ containing $Y$ then $\omega$ is integrable over $Y_\beta$ if and only if it is integrable over $Y_\alpha$ and in this case
> $$
> \int_{Y_\alpha}\omega=\pm\int_{Y_\beta}\omega
> $$

but unfortunately I did not conclude anything. However I am sure that using the change of variables theorem it is possible to prove that the above two quantities are equal unless the sign because the above matrix is the matrix of the identity map with respect the basis $\mathcal V$ and $\mathcal W$. Indeed we suppose that $\mathcal W$ is the standard basis of $\Bbb R^k$ and thus we define the diffeormorphism $\phi:\Bbb R^k\rightarrow\Bbb R^k$ through the position
$$
\phi(x):=x^iw^j_i\vec v_j=x^i\vec w_i=x
$$
for any $x\in\Bbb R^n$ so that by the change of variable theorem it follows that
$$
\int_{x\in A} f=\int_{y\in\phi^{-1}[A]}(f\circ \phi)|\det D\phi|=\int_{y\in A} f|\det[w^i_j]|=\pm\int_{y\in A} g
$$
as we desired.
However, I fear that there is some error in the above identity. So could anyone give some clarification about this, please?

Comment: @Digitallis The two bases are costant.

Comment: The $dx^i$ are orthonormal coordinates, in the sense that $dx^i(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$

Comment: @rubikscube09 Read the redit at the end.

Comment: What can you say about?

Comment: Anyway as I explained in the question I am interested about the case where the bases are **not** orthonormal!

Comment: It is not a question of whether the bases themselves are orthonormal - that requires a definition of an inner product on the spaces spanned by $\{v_1 , \cdots , v_k\}$, which is not defined a-priori. Given any basis we can actually choose an inner product s.t. the basis is orthonormal (the standard dot product for ex.)

Comment: The coordinates $dx^{i}$ are not elements of the space spanned by $\{v_1, \cdots , v_n\}$ but instead elements of the dual vector space $V^*$ (as I'm sure you know), which has nothing to do with the inner product on $V$ unless an inner product is specified.

Comment: So $dx^i$ is simply the dual basis of the basis $(x;\vec v_1),...,(x;\vec v_k)$ of $\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)$ and the dual basis (a basis of the **dual** space!) exist indipendetely by a particular inner product, that's all.

Comment: Yes - that's exactly correct.

Comment: I haven't read all this carefully. The point is that it's integrals of differential forms that are well-defined, not integrals of functions, when you make arbitrary changes of coordinates. (Just think about integrating the function $1$ and computing the underlying volume. This will change unless your change of coordinates is volume-preserving.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, so if $fdx^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dx^k=\omega=gdy^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dy^k$ where the first elementary forms are reffered to the usual basis of $\Bbb R^n$ and the second to other any basis then is it $\int_A fdx^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dx^k=\int_ A g dy^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dy^k$?

Comment: The forms are equal? And you're integrating over the same region $A$ (which will look different in the different parameter spaces)? Yes.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, so could you prove it, please? I will very grateful to you!

Comment: This is in Munkres, of course. This is well-definedness of the integral of a differential form. It's just the change of variables theorem. I'm not going to write it out.

Comment: @TedShifrin Unfortunately I am autodidact and I do not know anyone could help me.

Comment: @TedShifrin I thought this too but unfortunately it seems I do not be able to apply it as I said at the end of the question.

Comment: When you reduce to the multiple integrals, the integrals are over different regions, not the same region.

Comment: Oh, there! Surely it was this my mistake! So could you show it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f=1$ and the region $A\subset\Bbb R^2$ to be the rectangle spanned by $(1,0)$ and $(0,2)$. I consider the linear mapping $T(x^1,x^2)=(x^1,2x^2)=(y^1,y^2)$ mapping the unit square $Q$ to $A$. Then we have $\omega = dy^1\wedge dy^2 = 2\,dx^1\wedge dx^2$. What the second equals sign means, more carefully, is that $T^*\omega = 2\,dx^1\wedge dx^2$, as officially these $2$-forms are defined on different versions of $\Bbb R^2$. Now,
\begin{multline*}
2 = \int_A  dy^1\wedge dy^2 = \int_{T(Q)} dy^1\wedge dy^2 = \int_Q T^*(dy^1\wedge dy^2) \\= \int_Q 2\,dx^1\wedge dx^2 = 2\cdot 1.
\end{multline*}
This generalizes to any invertible linear map, of course.

Comment: Umm...it is unespected: so from you wrote I condude that the value of $dy^1\wedge dy^2$ in $A$ are different form the value of $2dx^1\wedge dx^2$ in the **same** region (**It's really like this?**) and thus to calclulate the theorem you apply the change of variable theorem for forms on parametrized manifold, right?

Comment: When you actually want to integrate a form over a fixed submanifold, you must pull back by the parametrization/chart, get a form on the parametrizing region in $\Bbb R^k$, and *then* convert to a multiple integral.

Comment: Okay, anyway what that surprise me is that if $\omega$ is a $k$-form defined in the open set $A$ of $\Bbb R^k$ and if I have two different functional expresion of it then only if this expressions are referred to an orthornormal basis I can integrate them components directely in the open set and this seems stranger with respect the definition of the integral over an open set: so where is my confusion?

Comment: I do not understand the issue. Whether you write it or not, when you write the differential form in two different coordinate systems, to say they are "equal" is to say that the pullback of one by the diffeomorphism $\phi$ relating the coordinate systems equals the other.

Comment: I think that my problem is the following: if $\omega=fdx^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dx^k=gdy^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dy^k$ is a $k$-form defined on $A$ then by definition $\int_A \omega:=\int _A f$ but the integral at the right side is calculate with respect the usual basis of $\Bbb R^k$ and thus $\int_A\omega\neq\int_A g$ so that if I like to calculate the integral of $\omega$ with respect $dy^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dy^k$ I have to calculate this elementary form in term of the usual one and then integrate on $A$ (otherwise over which set?), right?

Comment: I will encourage you to put in the pullbacks explicitly. You have a form $\omega$ on a subset of a manifold. When you write equals, you are suppressing the pullbacks by the parametrizations. Put them in explicitly. I've said this three times, so I don't see the point of saying it anymore.

Comment: Okay, so it holds the following identity $\int_A\omega=\int_A gdy^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge=\int_{T[A]}T^*[gdy^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dy^k]$ where $T$ is a linear transformation, right?

Comment: No, it's $T^{-1}(A)$. But when you even write the coordinate expression, there's a pullback there to $y$-space. To get back to $x$-space, there's the additional pullback by the mapping from $x$ to $y$.

Comment: I begin to understand: tonight I will reflect about you explained. Thanks too much for your assistance!!!

Comment: Sure. Have I already suggested you might want to look at my lectures on YouTube? They cover a lot of this material (in a slightly different way from Munkres) — no tensors for the differential forms. The link is in my profile.

Comment: I saw: unfortunately I am studying Differential Geometry because I would like to study continuum mechanics and the text on which I would like to study uses tensors; moreover I can only write and read English (I studied Latin -and Greek too- and thus to I use lexical and grammar affinities of English with respect Latin to study text in this leanguage) so that I have many difficults to understand any dialogue because the english phonetic is different a lot from the italian one.

Comment: Anyway I have reflected about what you have explained to me. So if $\omega$ is a differential form defined on the open set $A$ of $\Bbb R^k$ then $\omega=f dx^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dx^k$ with respect the usual basis and $\omega=gdy^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dy^k$ with respect another but in any case (using Munkres definition) the functional compontents $f$ and $g$ must be scalar functions defined in $A$ and thus I do not completely understand why I have to integrate the second function in another set different from $A$.

Comment: Indeed having defined the integral of $\omega$ with respect the usual basis I can explain this only cosidering $A$ as a manifold indetified by the linear diffeomorphism that maps the vectors corresponding to the form $dy^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dy^k$ to those of the standard basis so that I conclude that the definition given by Munkres is not free fashion. Thus the original question musted be: which can be a free fashion definition?

Comment: Forgive me for my talkativeness: unfortunately I reflect to what I study because as autodidact I would like to well understand it.

Comment: With more structure, e.g., a Riemannian metric, I can define various intrinsic geometric differential forms without reference to coordinate charts. But what do you mean? Even in one dimension you need a notion of unit length to define integrals. For double integrals, everything is based on unit squares, etc. So how can you, even in the badic setting, define integrals in a coordinate-free manner?

Comment: Okay, so I conclude that Munkres uses the expression *free fashion* for the following reason: since the modul of $k$-form in $\Bbb R^k$ is unit dimensional it follows that the functional component $f$ of a $k$-form $\omega:=f dx^1\curlywedge...\curlywedge dx^k$ with respect **any** orthonormal basis is uniquely determined unless the sign and thus the position $$\int_A\omega:=\int_A f$$ is free fashion with respect **ORTHONORMAL** basis, that's all. Could be this an adequate explanation?